# Assigning a number amount

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know that if I am assigning a number amount to a word that I can enter it in as:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:H3,"Yes")*20
```

But what if I also want the same cell to assign 10 if the answer is no? How would I write this? I tried:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:H3,"Yes")*20 =COUNTIF(D3:H3,"No")*10
```

But I assume that this is wrong because It is not working...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are requesting is

```
=COUNTIF(D3:H3,"Yes")*20 + COUNTIF(D3:H3,"No")*10
```